# setFormulaArray too slow

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I'm trying to write a python wrapper which is designed to read multiple records from csv(or mysql) and update values of a predefined range of a sheet, the range is consisted of value cells and formula cells, my purpose is to update value cells only and keep formula cells in the range unchanged.

In order to do this, I first tried setting cell values one by one, using `if` to skip formula cells, but it was to slow because there were more than 10 thousand cells, then I tried `setDataArray` which was fast enough but formulas were overrode by values, then I created an array and set values and formulas into the array and used `setFormulaArray` to put the values and formulas into the range, the function was what I needed, by it took more than one minutes to finish

I know the `setFormulaArray` will update the formulas but I don't need this to happen, however as there is no option in the API to skip formulas I can only use the same formula to update the original formula in a certain cell.

Is there any solution to improve the performance when using `setFormulaArry`, or is there any solution to update only value cells and skip formula cells in a range?
bellow is my code

```
import uno
import time


#to open the libreoffice calc file
local_ctx = uno.getComponentContext()
smgr_local = local_ctx.ServiceManager
resolver = smgr_local.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", local_ctx)
url = "uno:socket,host=localhost,port=2083,tcpNoDalay=1;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext"

uno_ctx = resolver.resolve(url)
uno_smgr = uno_ctx.ServiceManager
desktop = uno_smgr.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", uno_ctx )
PropertyValue = uno.getClass('com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue')
inProps = PropertyValue( "Hidden" , 0 , True, 0 )
document = desktop.loadComponentFromURL("file:///D:/salse.ods", "_blank", 0, inProps )


# get the sheet and read original data and formula from the sheet
sheets = document.getSheets()
xs = sheets["salse"]
cursor=xs.createCursor()
cursor.gotoStartOfUsedArea(False)
cursor.gotoEndOfUsedArea(True)
cra=cursor.getRangeAddress()


rng=xs.getCellRangeByPosition(cra.StartColumn,cra.StartRow,cra.EndColumn,cra.EndRow)
ft=rng.getFormulaArray()

#some code here to change values in ft.... 


# bellow took more than one minutes
rng.setFormulaArray(ft)
```

it is only a test of setFormulaArray performance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why do you think that "*there is no option in the API to skip formulas*"? What about `crngs=cursor.queryContentCells(7)`? Then `.getCells()`, `.createEnumeration()` and while `.hasMoreElements()` do `.nextElement()`... See [**here**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XCellRangesQuery.html#queryContentCells) and [**here**](http://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/sheet/XSheetCellRanges.html#getCells)... or just use [**MRI**](https://github.com/hanya/MRI)

Comment: Thank you for answering, I meant _"there is no option to skip formula"_  when **setting values** , ideally, I was expecting something like `setDataArray(data=somedata, skip_formula_cells=True)`, which would automatically jump to the next value cell when encountering a formula cell.     However it is helpful of your suggestion, I tested `queryContentCells(7)` and it returned with divied pieces of ranges, then I could call `setDataArray` on each of these sub ranges, it's not that perfect, but can improve performance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

update1:

I still can't find the ideal solution,however, my solution is to create an identical sheet for each of the sheets in the workbook and add ,in the original sheets, references to the newly created  sheets on the precisely same cells, for example:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqogS.png)

sheetA is the original sheet

sheetA-1 is newly created one

then modify data cells in sheetA to reference to sheetA-1

then setDataArray to update the entire range in sheetA-1, data will automatically change in corresponding cells in sheetA